# jQuery menu content changer default content

Tags: jquery, html, menu, default

I recently posted about some base code I was using to make a webpage change its contents based on the menu item that was pushed. Here's the code.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="menu" style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="tab" id="tab" style="display:inline-block;"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
    <div class="tab" id="tab" style="display:inline-block;"><a href="#">Page 1</a></div>
    <div class="tab" id="tab" style="display:inline-block;"><a href="#">Page 2</a></div>
    <div class="tab" id="tab" style="display:inline-block;"><a href="#">Page 3</a></div>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center">Selection options from menu above</div>

    <div id="main" class="main">
    <div id="content" class="content">
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <p>Home Page Text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="content">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
        <p>Page 1 Text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="content">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>        
        <p>Page 2 Text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="content">        
        <h1>Page 3</h1>
        <p>Page 3 Text</p>
    </div>                 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tab a').click(function(e){
     hideContentDivs();
     var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
     $('.main #content').eq(tmp_div).show();
  });
function hideContentDivs(){
    $('.main #content').each(function(){
    $(this).hide();});
}
hideContentDivs();
});
```

The problem I'm having is theres not default content so no content appears until a link is pressed, I'd prefer the "home" text to be the default content shown. Can anyone tell me how to do this?
I'm basically trying to make a website appear on a single web page so if anyone has any better ideas of how to achieve this please let me know but I must be able to use divs in the changeable content as I need to display and position pictures.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the 0 sequence your default content to show up on load.

**http://jsfiddle.net/QYNC4/1/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#tab a').click(function(e){
     hideContentDivs();
     var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
     $('.main #content').eq(tmp_div).show();
  });
function hideContentDivs(){
    $('.main #content').each(function(){
    $(this).hide();});
}
hideContentDivs();
    $('.main #content').eq(0).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to do it would be to trigger a click on docReady (I'm CERTAIN there is a better way than this btw):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#tab a').click(function(e){
     hideContentDivs();
     var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
     $('.main #content').eq(tmp_div).show();
  });

 function hideContentDivs(){
    $('.main #content').each(function(){
    $(this).hide();});
 }

hideContentDivs();
$("#tab a").first().click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and solution but I've gone with the other answer.